# Route to image in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am using the Laravel framework and trying to display an image in a view. Here is the code in the show template that displays the image.

`<img src="storage/cover_images/{{$post->cover_image}}">`

In this file, I define the storage directory for the image

[image]

But the image won't show in the browser, it just pointing to this path
`http://localhost/lsapp/public/posts/storage/cover_images/noimage.jpg` while my images are in the `lsapp/storage/app/public/cover_images` folder.

Comment: Can you please post your code in the question itself, rather than in an image?

Comment: Looks like your app setup is wrong. There should be no mention of the `public` folder in your urls. `public` should be the `DocumentRoot` of your webserver/virtualhost.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output. Please post CODE and not pictures of code

Comment: Try using `storage_path('app/public/cover_images/' . $post->cover_image)`. You could also append the directory to the storage_path call if it doesn't work.
Also as kerbholz suggested, you should be able to remove the `/lsapp/public` portion of your hrefs and something like `/posts` should be picked up properly in the routing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question..as you want to display image in view.

run Command: `php artisan storage:link`

after that now you can display your image in view using `Storage:url`

```
<img src="{{ Storage:url($post->cover_image) }}">
```

Make sure to post code next time instead of screenshot.